# Python openpyxl formula incorrectly displayed in Excel

Tags: python, excel, excel-formula, openpyxl

I have a problem with the correct export of a formula via Python openpyxl in Excel. I want to export the formula for the average and the 75% quartile over a range in Excel. I am using the German Excel version. This works quite well for the average, here the English formula "=AVERAGE(A2:A7)" is shown as the German formula "=MITTELWERT(A2:A7)". Unfortunately, this does not work for the 75% quartile, here the English formula "=QUARTILE.INC(A2:A7,75%)" is shown as "=@QUARTILE.INC(A2:A7;75%)", which leads to an error in Excel, and not as the German formula "=QUARTILE.INKL(A2:A7; 0,75)", which would work.
Here is a sample code:

```
import pandas as pd
import os

# Change directory
directory = r'C:\Users\abc\Desktop\Test Formula'
os.chdir(directory)

# Create dataframe
data = {
    'Test1': [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6],
    'Test2': [16.46, 17.21, 14.98, 21.3, 89.1, 71.77]
}

data['Test1'].append('=AVERAGE(A2:A7)')
data['Test2'].append('=AVERAGE(B2:B7)')

data['Test1'].append('=QUARTILE.INC(A2:A7,75%)')
data['Test2'].append('=QUARTILE.INC(B2:B7,75%)')

df = pd.DataFrame(data)

# Create an Excel file
output_file = os.path.join(directory, "Output.xlsx")
with pd.ExcelWriter(output_file, engine='openpyxl') as writer:  # Specify engine='openpyxl'
    df.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Test_Output', index=False)
```

In (the German) Excel, this code will produce the following formulas/evaluations:

=MITTELWERT(A2:A7) (evaluates correctly to 3.5),

=@QUARTILE.INC(A2:A7;75%) (evaluates incorrectly to #NAME?)

Instead of =@QUARTILE.INC(A2:A7;75%), there should be =QUARTILE.INKL(A2:A7; 0,75) (which would correctly evaluate to 1).
Does anyone have an idea why this code does not produce the correct formula in Excel?

Comment: what happens if you enter `=@QUARTILE.INC(A2:A7;75%)` in German Excel? Why not use `'=QUARTILE.INKL(A2:A7; 0,75)'` as formula in python?

Comment: When I enter =@QUARTILE.INC(A2:A7;75%) in German Excel, it gives me #NAME? (i.e., it doesn´t recognize the formula). If I use =QUARTILE.INKL(A2:A7; 0,75) in python, it doesn´t even show me any formula in this cell in the Excel output (i.e., the cell where this formula should be is just blank)

Comment: Regarding '=QUARTILE.INKL(A2:A7; 0,75)' in python: The cell in Excel is likely not directly empty, but when I open the output file, Excel shows me a message box that there is a problem with this file. When I close this message box, the cell where the formula should be is empty

Comment: Actually [there is note in openpyxl docs](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/simple_formulae.html#using-formulae): _NB **you must use the English name for a function** and function arguments must be separated by commas and not other punctuation such as semi-colons._

Comment: According to my understanding, I use the correct English names of the Excel functions in the Python code:

data['Test1'].append('=AVERAGE(A2:A7)')

and 

data['Test1'].append('=QUARTILE.INC(A2:A7,75%)').

For the mean, it gives me the correct function in Excel as result (i.e., '=MITTELWERT(A2:A7)'), but for the 75% quartile, the function in Excel is not working (i.e., '=@QUARTILE.INC(A2:A7;75%)') and should be '=QUARTILE.INKL(A2:A7; 0,75)'

Comment: Excel does all kinds of magic with formulae, of which local language names and punctuation is just the tip of the iceberg. The `@` prefix usually denotes some form of array formula but the only way to be sure is to look at the XML source of the relevant file and use Openpyxl to produce just that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add `_xlfn.`
Below should work:

```
data['Test1'].append('=_xlfn.QUARTILE.INC(A2:A7,75%)')
data['Test2'].append('=_xlfn.QUARTILE.INC(B2:B7,75%)')
```

Here is the note from openpyxl:
[openpyxl doc](https://openpyxl.readthedocs.io/en/stable/simple_formulae.html#using-formulae):

[image]

Comment: This is sometimes required but not in this case as `QUARTILE` is in the list of formulae.

Comment: I can reproduce the #NAME error and this _xlfn fix it. May be has something to do with Python version or openpyxl version.

Comment: It could be the `.INC` suffix.

Comment: Yes, that is what I figured. PERCENTIL.EXC or INC also have this problem.